# Is there a way to execute a single Dataform file (action) with Airflow (not executing a tag, only a single action\sqlx file)?

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x, dataform

I'm trying to execute a single Dataform task with Airflow 2 (Google Composer).
I found a way to run a workflow by the tag name = x, so all sqlx\js files with the tag name = x, will run.
In the Dataform file it is configured like this:

```
config {
  type: "table",
  database:"aaa",
  schema: "bbb",
  tags: ["x"]
}
```

Now I'm trying to run a single file (sqlx\js) which has no tag without success.
For running a specific tag I'm using invocation_config with included_tags:

```
DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
    task_id='create_workflow_invocation',
    dag=dag,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
    workflow_invocation={
        'compilation_result': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_compilation_result')['name'] }}",
        'invocation_config': {"included_tags": ["x"]}
    }
)
```

Is there a way to run a single file with no tag?
Thanks

I have tried to find a new property instead of included_tags but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/InvocationConfig). But they are not completely accurate. I do it as follows.

```
def create_action_run_task(task_id, target):
    task = DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
        workflow_invocation={
        "compilation_result": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_compilation_result')['name'] }}",
        'invocation_config': {"included_targets": [target]}
        },
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Target format is: {'schema': 'schema_name', 'name': 'table_name', 'database': 'database_name'}

Answer (score 0):

At the moment. There is no way to Run a single action or TAGs in Dataform programmatically, so Airflow does not support it yet.

The only way is to run all actions in the same Release.

All Documentation Examples to trigger "Actions" always use Dataform UI, and there are no examples using **gcloud** CMD or **libs**

https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/trigger-execution